# does React apply its reconciliation algorithm on consecutive calls to ReactDOM.render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question seems trivial at first look, but I could not find an answer to it, so maybe it is not so. Basically I want to use React as a DOM library, with no use of state, i.e. no use of classes. I have top level function component, which takes props, as usual. I render it as recommended through ReactDOM.render. Then somewhere new props will be computed, and I want to rerender the component based on those new props. All the previous similar questions on SO have answers which invariably somewhere use a `setState` call to do so, but here I do not have classes so there is no `this.setState` available to me.

What I tried is :

```
function App(props){
...
}
// using hyperscript here in lieu of jsx
ReactDOM.render(h(App, {..the props..}), document.getElementById('root'));
... later props change, repeat 
ReactDOM.render(h(App, {..the props..}), document.getElementById('root'));
```

My question is : if I do it this way, does React still apply its reconciliation algorithm for efficient DOM update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at the documentation for `ReactDOM.render()`: https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html we can see the following:

> React DOM compares the element and its children to the previous one, and only applies the DOM updates necessary to bring the DOM to the desired state.

This is illustrated via an example that calls `render()` every second:

```
function tick() {
  const element = (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      <h2>It is {new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>
    </div>
  );
  ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
}

setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

If you run this code with the browser devtools open, you can see that only the updated part of the DOM is updated each time `render()` is called:

> Even though we create an element describing the whole UI tree on every
>   tick, only the text node whose contents has changed gets updated by
>   React DOM.

So I think the short answer is: **Yes, React still applies the reconciliation algorithm.**

Also, from my own experience, I've used a similar model when integrating React components into applications build with other frameworks (e.g. Angular) and observed the same behaviour when updating the React components.

Comment: Matt I got your answer and forgot to thank you. So thank you :-)